# Combining Angular's FormBuilder with async code (Observables)

Tags: angular, observable, angular-formbuilder

I have an array of Observables which I'm displaying via Angular's async pipe in a form. The `devices$` array is dynamic, I'm adding elements to it via button click.

```
<form [formGroup]="devices_form" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
   <div *ngFor="let device of devices$">
      <div *ngIf="device | async as device">
        <input value="{{ device.name }}">
        <input value="{{ device.type }}">
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I now need to submit the data (`name` etc.) of `devices$` via Angular's FormBuilder. I guess I need to first map / iterate
the `devices$` array, subscribe to its elements and push the results to a FormGroup field.

Although I'm confused because my Observables are async of course and when submitting the form I have to make sure that my data is "complete", if that makes any sense. Until now I do not manually subscribe to the Observables in my TypeScript code.

Here's my simplified code:

```
// Interface of device
export interface Device {
 name: string,
 type: string
}

// Devices form I need to submit
this.devices_form = this.formBuilder.group({
   devices: ['', Validators.required]
});

// Submit form if valid
submitForm() {

   // I guess I need to set the devices value here
   this.devices_form.get('devices').setValue('array data here...');

   if (this.devices_form.valid) {
      this.saveData(this.devices_form.value);
   }
}
```

I already tried mapping `devices$`, subscribing to its elements and adding this to the FormGroup. Although, since it's async data, it didn't work properly (because a Subscription is never 'finished', I didn't receive the correct amount of elements). I also played around with FormArray (from Angular) but wasn't successful.

Does anybody know how to combine async code with an array of Observables and Angular's FormBuilder?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It might be easier if you have an observable of an array instead of an array of observables. (There might even be RxJS operator that makes that conversion.)

Comment: @ekalin that's true but unfortunately an array of observables is all I have and I can't change that. Otherwise RxJS operators would be an option.

Comment: Perhaps one of the solutions here might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47972512/rxjs-observable-of-array-for-array-of-observables